# Postition Relative on display:table-row

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-tables

I have a table comprised of div's using table css to style it into a table format.  I want to lock out a single row with an absolutely positioned div inside of the row.  However when I do this the position:relative; set on the row is not respected.

This is my table without trying to lock the row.

[jsfiddle table without locked row](http://jsfiddle.net/50tonrobot/jmn60e3e/)

When I set the row locker div to display:block. It completely breaks out of the table row.

(run as the code is below; stackoverflow did not allow me to post a third link)

When I set the divRow class to be display:block instead of display:table-row; the row blocker div sits in the right place (what I want), but all of the columns get pushed to the left as I lose the functionality of the table-row attribute (what I don't want).

[jsfiddle with divRow set to block](http://jsfiddle.net/50tonrobot/fxs3r24q/)

Here is the code I am using to produce these results.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .divTable{
          display:table;         
          width:auto;
          position: relative;              
        }
        .divRow{
          display:table-row;
          width:auto;
          clear:both;
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
        .divCell{
          display:table-cell;
          padding: 3px;        
          vertical-align: top;
          position: relative;
        }
        .locked_row
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main_content">
        <div class="divTable">
            <div class="divRow" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>John</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="divRow" style="background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);">
                <div class="divCell"><span>id: 832</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Jane</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="divRow" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>John</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="divRow" style="background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);">
                <div class="divCell"><span>id: 832</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Jane</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="divRow" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>John</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span></div>
                <div class='locked_row'><span>This row is locked</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="divRow" style="background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);">
                <div class="divCell"><span>id: 832</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Jane</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Some other long data in a row</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="divRow" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>John</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="divRow" style="background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);">
                <div class="divCell"><span>id: 83223425</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Really Long user name</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="divRow" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>John</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="divRow" style="background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);">
                <div class="divCell"><span>id: 832</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Jane</span></div>
                <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what 'locking' a row means.  What are you trying to get the red div to actually do here.

Comment: I'm suspecting you are trying to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/fxs3r24q/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Here are two ideas

### #1 - Remove text and colour background of cells (easiest)

- Remove the text of locked cells from the viewport with `text-indent: -9999px`
- Provide the text "Locked" with a `position: absolute` pseudo element of the cells. `left: 9999px` pulls the text back into the viewport for  this element.
- The cells are given `position: relative`

#### Working Example

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
}
.divRow {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.divCell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.divRow:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
.divRow:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.lockedRow > div {
  background: #F00;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  position: relative;
}
.lockedRow > div:first-child:after {
  content: 'Locked Row';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 9999px;
  top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="main_content">
  <div class="divTable">
    <div class="divRow lockedRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>John</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 832</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Jane</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>John</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow lockedRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 832</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Jane</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>John</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 832</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Jane</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Some other long data in a row</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>John</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 83223425</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Really Long user name</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>John</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 832</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Jane</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### #2 - Overlap row

This idea seems to work best when applied to children of each "cell".

Apply the locked class to the row and then create a lock overlay with a pseudo element of `.divCell` like this:

```
.lockedRow > div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

The cells of the locked row are made position relative:

```
.lockedRow > div {
  position: relative;
}
```

The locked message can be given through the first cell:

```
.lockedRow > div:first-child:after {
  content: 'Locked Row';
}
```

Also, apply the background row colours with `nth-child`:

```
.divRow:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
 }
.divRow:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 }
```

#### Working Example

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
}
.divRow {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.divCell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.lockedRow > div {
  position: relative;
}
.lockedRow > div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.lockedRow > div:first-child:after {
  content: 'Locked Row';
}

.divRow:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  }
.divRow:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
```

```html
<div id="main_content">
  <div class="divTable">
    <div class="divRow lockedRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>John</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 832</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Jane</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>John</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow lockedRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 832</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Jane</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>John</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 832</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Jane</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Some other long data in a row</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>John</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 83223425</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Really Long user name</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 234</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>johnDoe23</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>John</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
      <div class="divCell"><span>id: 832</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>janeDoe288</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Jane</span>
      </div>
      <div class="divCell"><span>Doe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, are the spans really needed? They seem redundant.